# AJAX Request to get most recent, unique messages from chat database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a chat script with PHP and MySQL and AJAX, but I'm really new to javascript, and while the ajax call works, it shows the same messages multiple times (and continues to do so). This is my Javascript:

```
var chatUpdate = function(mLID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getChat/mID/" + mLID,
        success: function(data) {
            // do something with "data"
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var page = $(data);
                var time = page.find('#time').html();
                console.log(time);
                var statusText = page.find('#msg').html();
                var mID = page.find('#msgID').text();
                console.log(mID);
                console.log(page.find('#msg').html());
                $("#chatTable").append(statusText);
                setInterval(chatUpdate(mID), 2500);
            }
        }
    });
};
if(!mID){
    var mID = "0";
}
setInterval(chatUpdate(mID), 2500);
```

And my serverside script is simply a mysql query that shows the data:

```
        $query = "SELECT `chat`.*, `users`.* FROM `chat` JOIN `users` ON `uid` = `cUID` WHERE `cid` > '$mID'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        if(count($row) > 0){
        echo "<div id='msg'><div style='display:table-row;'><div style='display:table-cell;'><strong>" .$row['username']. "</strong>: </div><div style='display:table-cell;'>" .$row['msg']. "</div></div></div><div id='time'>".$row['time']."</div><div id='msgID'>".$row['cid']."</div>";
        }
```

What I'm asking is if anyone can help me to make the script only show each message once, and stop showing messages until there's a new one. I've tried other ways with AJAX, but they give me the same result as this one (or they just tell me that the values are undefined in the console and stop the script.

Please remember that I'm new to JS, so if this seems simple to you, it may not be to me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's because you're query is the same every time. Assuming you have a primary_key for every message, you should do something with your MySQL that utilizes something like `ORDER BY primary_key DESC LIMIT 20`.

Comment: @PHPglue But, when it runs out of messages, it stops checking for them. It's also not a while loop, so it will only get one row regardless.

Comment: That is also true. You are replicating an HTML id attribute as well. You never checked `if($data->num_rows > 0){}` either before you run the while loop. Personally, when I use AJAX, I just use PHP to produce JSON, with `json_encode()`, creating all the HTML on the Client Side, since I may be creating Events at the same time anyways. I believe that you should change your entire approach to Object Oriented.

Comment: @PHPglue `count($row)` does the comparison, and there's a different value in the div each time it makes a new request(unless there are no more messages), so the duplication shouldn't matter.

Comment: That is not what this code does. You should check the number of rows before you fetch anything. `id='msg'` is `echo`ed every time, and only the first row of the results. Every time you call your fetch method it retrieves a new row of results. Since you are not running this in a while loop it just deals with the first result row. It's being called again and again because of `setInterval()`, which is fine, but really you should look into my original comment.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, I think the simplest way is to pass in the html message an attribute which will be fill with the id of the message.
And when you make you're ajax call with jQuery you can easily get the id of the last message you have already display and pass this information to php to only get newer message than this one.

Comment: That works until you run out of messages, and then the ajax script stops